# How to find or get exact value from python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

suppose I find all scripts using bs4soup

scripts= soup.find_all('script')

got all the script list, now if I need only index no 15 script, starting **var numreported = 0;**

how do I find or extract that script only?

Though **var numreported = 0; script keeps changing the 15 index position to 16, 17 or somewhere.**

```
[<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-789618-4"></script>, <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-789618-4');
</script>, <script async="" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>, <script src="/photoswipe/photoswipe.min.js"></script>, <script src="/photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>, <script async="" defer="" src="//services.bilsyndication.com/adv1/?d=1281" type="text/javascript"></script>, <script>
                var vitag = vitag || {};
                if ('outStreamConfig' in vitag == false ) vitag.outStreamConfig = {};
                vitag.outStreamConfig.enablePC = false;
                vitag.outStreamConfig.enableMobile= false;
                vitag.smartBannerConfig = vitag.smartBannerConfig || {};
                vitag.smartBannerConfig.enablePC = false;
                vitag.smartBannerConfig.enableMobile = false;
                </script>, <script type="text/javascript">
                var infolinks_pid = 3029683;
                var infolinks_wsid = 0;
                </script>, <script src="//resources.infolinks.com/js/infolinks_main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>, <script language="Javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ouibounce/0.0.12/ouibounce.min.js"></script>, <script language="JavaScript" src="/wikifeet.js?ver=10"></script>, <script>
        messanger['gender'] = 1;
        messanger['mbf'] = 1;

    function Get(name)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }

    function Class(name, cname)
    {
        Get(name).className = cname;
    }


</script>, <script type="application/ld+json">{
                                        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
                                        "@type": "CreativeWorkSeries",
                                        "name": "Taylor Bennett's Feet",
                                        "aggregateRating":
                                        {
                                                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                                                "bestRating": "5",
                                                "ratingValue": "3.67",
                                                "ratingCount": "40",
                                                "description": "Rated 3.67/5 stars"
                                  }     }
                                }</script>, <script async="" src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>, <script>  
                        //gtag('event', 'Gallery Views', { 'event_label': 'Taylor-Bennett'});
                        messanger.cid  = 8562959;
                        messanger.cfname = 'Taylor-Bennett';
                        messanger.originalRank = 0;
                        messanger.userid = 0;
                        messanger.nickname = '';
                        messanger.profile = 0;
                        messanger.eus = 0;
                        messanger.glevel = 0;
                        messanger.fav = new Array();
                        messanger.fav[8562959] = 0;
                        messanger.pidlist = new Array();
                        </script>, <script>
        var numreported = 0;
        messanger['tagname'] = {"C":"Close-up","A":"Arches","N":"Nylons","B":"Barefoot","T":"Toenails","S":"Soles"};
        messanger['gdata'] = [{"similarity":null,"reported":"0","tags":"","ureported":null,"new":0,"gid":0,"pw":750,"pid":4612500,"ph":1334,"closest":null},{"ph":1080,"pid":4612505,"closest":4612500,"gid":0,"pw":1080,"new":0,"reported":"0","similarity":331,"tags":"","ureported":null},{"ureported":null,"tags":"","reported":"0","similarity":324,"new":0,"pw":1080,"gid":0,"pid":4612506,"closest":4612500,"ph":1080},{"pid":4836419,"ph":1235,"closest":4612500,"gid":0,"pw":1242,"new":0,"reported":"0","similarity":331,"tags":"","ureported":null},{"ureported":null,"similarity":250,"reported":"0","tags":"","new":0,"pw":1242,"gid":0,"pid":4836420,"ph":1253,"closest":4836419},{"new":0,"ureported":null,"similarity":312,"reported":"0","tags":"","pid":4836422,"closest":4836419,"ph":1550,"pw":1242,"gid":0},{"gid":0,"pw":1242,"closest":4836419,"pid":4836423,"ph":1561,"reported":"0","similarity":285,"tags":"","ureported":null,"new":0},{"ureported":null,"reported":"0","similarity":305,"tags":"","new":0,"pw":1099,"gid":0,"pid":5567104,"closest":4836419,"ph":1412},{"similarity":303,"reported":"0","tags":"","ureported":null,"new":0,"gid":0,"pw":1188,"ph":1188,"pid":5910453,"closest":4836419},{"pid":5930819,"ph":2048,"closest":4836419,"pw":1354,"gid":0,"new":0,"ureported":null,"similarity":291,"reported":"0","tags":""},{"pw":588,"gid":0,"pid":6101012,"ph":688,"closest":4836419,"ureported":null,"similarity":273,"tags":"","reported":"0","new":0},{"reported":"0","similarity":235,"tags":"","ureported":null,"new":0,"gid":0,"pw":1080,"ph":713,"pid":6101013,"closest":6101012},{"closest":6101013,"pid":6330671,"ph":1737,"gid":0,"pw":448,"new":0,"similarity":172,"tags":"","reported":"0","ureported":null},{"pid":6330672,"closest":6101013,"ph":1268,"pw":447,"gid":0,"new":0,"ureported":null,"reported":"0","similarity":177,"tags":""},{"ph":1291,"pid":6345943,"closest":6101013,"gid":0,"pw":1080,"new":0,"reported":"0","tags":"","similarity":169,"ureported":null},{"new":0,"tags":"","similarity":170,"reported":"D","ureported":null,"ph":1350,"pid":6381583,"closest":6101013,"gid":0,"pw":1080},{"ureported":null,"similarity":173,"tags":"","reported":"0","new":0,"pw":1717,"gid":0,"ph":1337,"pid":6388872,"closest":6101013},{"new":0,"reported":"0","tags":"","similarity":165,"ureported":null,"ph":1350,"pid":6528752,"closest":6101013,"gid":0,"pw":1080},{"ph":700,"pid":6543593,"closest":6101013,"pw":613,"gid":0,"new":0,"ureported":null,"similarity":168,"reported":"0","tags":""},{"closest":6101013,"pid":6543594,"ph":802,"gid":0,"pw":720,"new":0,"reported":"0","similarity":171,"tags":"","ureported":null},{"pid":6577840,"ph":1350,"closest":6101013,"gid":0,"pw":1080,"new":0,"reported":"0","similarity":157,"tags":"","ureported":null},{"pid":6582034,"closest":6101013,"ph":720,"pw":1080,"gid":0,"new":0,"ureported":null,"similarity":157,"reported":"0","tags":""},{"new":0,"ureported":null,"reported":"0","similarity":169,"tags":"","closest":6101013,"pid":6619826,"ph":1799,"pw":1440,"gid":0},{"ureported":null,"reported":"0","similarity":166,"tags":"","new":1,"pw":1440,"gid":0,"closest":6101013,"pid":6939532,"ph":1777},{"pid":6939533,"ph":1782,"closest":6101013,"gid":0,"pw":1440,"new":1,"similarity":166,"reported":"0","tags":"","ureported":null}];
        for (var i in messanger['gdata'])
        {
                messanger.pexist[messanger['gdata'][i].pid] = 1;
                if (messanger['gdata'][i].reported != '0') numreported++;
        }

                var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
                if (hash == 'reports') document.getElementById('gdatasort').value = 'rep';
        if (getCookie('nophotos') == 'true') {}
        else pDisplayPage(0, 1);
        </script>, <script>(vitag.Init = window.vitag.Init || []).push(function(){viAPItag.display("vi_12813030")})</script>, <script>
                        messanger['scrollfunc'] = LoadOlderComments;
                        window.onscroll = function() { messanger['scrollfunc'](); }
                </script>, <script>messanger['lastcomment'] = '';</script>, <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha512-yXXqOFjdjHNH1GND+1EO0jbvvebABpzGKD66djnUfiKlYME5HGMUJHoCaeE4D5PTG2YsSJf6dwqyUUvQvS0vaA==" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.1/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>, <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        window.cookieconsent.initialise({
          "palette": {
            "popup": {
              "background": "#000"
            },
            "button": {
              "background": "#f1d600"
            }
          }
        })});
        </script>]
```

Comment: you can walk through list and check every script text that contains required string.

Comment: can you please guide me? with an example please?

Answer (score 1):

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'var numreported = 0;' in script.getText().lower():
        print(script.getText())
```

Comment: wow i didn't tried this .getText().lower() rest of for and if loop i tried. thank you so much

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solution if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method to find what you want :

```
import re
def find(t1, t2) :
  ma =re.search(t1,t2)
  if ma :
    return ma.group() 
  else:
    print ('not found')
```

now you can use it :

```
scripts= soup.find_all('script')
t2 = str(scripts) 
result = find (r'<script>\.*var numreported = 0\.*</script>', t2)
```

but I dont know if *scripts* here is normal python list or some kind of cursor or somthing else, if *scripts* is python list it must work, if it is not list you have to find way to make it string first!